# C the same output different results

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void) {

  int m=2, a=5, b=4;
  float c=3.0, d=4.0;

  printf("%.2f,%.2f\n", (a/b)*m, (a/d)*m);
  printf("%.2f,%.2f\n", (a/d)*m, (a/b)*m);

  return 0;
}
```

The result is:

```
2.50,0.00
2.50,-5487459522906928958771870404376799406808566324353377030104786519743796498661129086808599726405487030183023928761546165866809436788166721199470577627133198744209879004896284033606071946689658593354711574682628407789000148729336462084532657713450945423953627239707603534923756075420253339949731915621203968.00
```

I want to know what cause this difference.

However, if I change **int** to **float**, the answer is the same as I expect.

The result is:

```
2.50,2.50
2.50,2.50
```

Comment: `%d` should be used to print `int`s.

Comment: Using incorrect format specifiers is undefined behavior, is your question why `(a/b)*m` evaluates to an `int`?

Comment: Your question is not clear, we can see the outputs, its normal, but what do you expect?

Comment: Are you saying the output in the second case is after changing a, b and m to be `float` rather than `int`, and you want to know why ? `(a/b)*m` when all three are `int` is `int` as a result. Sending that to `printf` with a `%.2f` format specifier is UB. That's the short of it.

Comment: Compile with `-Wall`. What do you see?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using wrong format specifiers, try this:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int m=2,a=5,b=4;
    float fm=2,fa=5,fb=4;
    float c=3.0,d=4.0;

 //First expression in this printf is int and second is float due to d
    printf("%d , %.2f\n\n",(a/b)*m,(a/d)*m); 

 //Second expression in this printf is int and first is float due to d
    printf("%.2f , %d\n\n",(a/d)*m,(a/b)*m); 

    printf("%.2f , %.2f\n\n",(fa/b)*fm,(fa/d)*fm);
    printf("%.2f , %.2f\n\n",(fa/d)*fm,(fa/b)*fm);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
2 , 0

0 , 1074003968

2.50 , 2.50

2.50 , 2.50
```

Section 7.19.6.1 p9 of the C99 standard says:

> If any argument is not the correct type for the corresponding conversion specification, the behavior is undefined.

Comment: `(a/d)*m` does *not* get promoted to `int`. It stays `float` due to the `d` introduction. The second specifier in the first `printf` and the first specifier in the second `printf` should be a `%f` derivation.

Comment: @WhozCraig - Yes you are correct and *also* the first specifier in second printf.

Comment: which means the first and second `printf` are synonymous save for order of output and specifiers. Not sure what the point of the second one is.

Answer (score 1):

Note that `a/b` is `int` if both are `int`s and is `float` if at least one is `float`, and similarly for other arithmetic operators. Thus in `a/b`, if they both are `int`s then 5/4 = 1; if at least one is `float`, then 5/4.0 = 5.0/4.0 = 1.25, because the compiler automatically converts an `int` into a `float` before any arithmetics with another float. So your results were expected to be different.

But in your case you seem to use the `%.2f` format even when you output `int`s. So `print` takes the four bytes that have your `int` and tries to decode those four bytes as if they had some `float` encoded. Flot numbers are encoded very differently in memory from `int`s -- it's like taking a Hungarian text and tryint to interpret it as if it was written in English, even if the letters are the same -- the resulting "interpretation" will be just garbage.

What you need to do: any `int` should be output with `%d` and any `float` with `%f` or similar formats.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to print integer values

```
printf("%d,%.2f\n",(a/b)*m,(a/d)*m);
printf("%.2f , %d\n\n",(a/d)*m,(a/b)*m);
```

In order to print integer values you should use `%d` using wrong format specifier lead to undefined behavior

Comment: The first output of the output statement a / b * m, the second output statement also outputs the a / b * m, but their different values

Answer (score 0):

If you want the result to be in float cast them:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    // your code goes here
    int m=2,a=5,b=4;
    float c=3.0,d=4.0;
    printf("%.2f,%.2f\n",(float)(a/b)*m,(float)(a/d)*m);
    printf("%.2f,%.2f\n", (float) (a/d)*m,(float)((a/b)*m));
    return 0;
}
```

Hope this helps..:)